# How to import several SSIS Packages to Data Tools Solution automatically?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, sql-server-data-tools, ssis-2012

I'm in charge of new system which has over 200 to 300 SSIS 2012 Packages(.dtsx). For our verification, I'd like to import those SSIS Packages to Solutions, as we can check exactly how their tasks work in each Packages, using SQL Server Data Tools.

I know we can manually import each SSIS Package to Solution, by right-click menu as import existing package one by one, but unfortunately we have only limited time for our verification.

So just wondering is there any way to import Packages to Data Tools Solution automatically ?

And We have Excel job list with package name. So, would be more grateful if we could import each Packages according this Package list.

Thank you so much for your any advice and idea in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### 1. Copy/Paste dtsx files

You can simply copy packages in the File explorer and in visual studio, go to solution explorer tab, right click on Packages folder and press Paste.

- [Add Multiple Packages to BIDS Solution](https://dataqueen.unlimitedviz.com/2012/07/add-multiple-packages-to-bids-solution/)

---

### 2. Use Add existing Item option

You can simply use add existing Item instead of add existing package and select multiple dtsx file at once

- [SSIS Trick: Adding Multiple Packages to a Project](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/ssis-trick-adding-multiple-packages-to-a-project)
- [Add Multiple Existing Packages to an SSIS Project at One Time](https://www.anexinet.com/blog/add-multiple-existing-packages-to-an-ssis-project-at-one-time/)

Comment: Many thanks for your precious information and useful link, Hadi !! We can make it organize hundreds packages by your #2. Thank you so much :)